VSCode can't use modules loaded with LOAD_PATH paths
I added custom path to LOAD_PATH and it works, but the VSCode introspection doesn't when I click on hi() function, VSCode can't find its definition.
I also tried adding path to JULIA_LOAD_PATH environment variable, it works with julia, but VSCode doesn't work ether.
How to fix it?
/projects/julia_test/
  SomeModule.jl
  run.jl

module Hi
  export hi
  hi() = "hi"
end

push!(LOAD_PATH, "/projects/julia_test")

using Hi

print(hi())

